# Getting "undefined reference error" when creating an object

Tags: c++, heap, linker-errors, nodes

The first part of my Heap code:

```
Heap::Heap()
{
 MAX = 256;
 size = 0;
 data = new Hnode*[MAX];
}
```

My main file is simply:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib>
#include "heap.h"

int main()
{
 string encodedData = "abracadabra";
 Heap heap;
}
```

I get an error when I call to make a heap saying: undefined reference to Heap::Heap and then as well for my destructor: undefined reference to Heap::~Heap()

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard to say with that little code samples. I assume your class and method definitions are in the header file "heap.h", aren't they? Maybe you should show more of your header then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have class declaration in `heap.h` and definition in `heap.cpp`

It seems you have not specified `heap.cpp` when you compiled, so the linker is not able to find the definitions

Try doing `g++ main.cpp heap.cpp`